# setuptools won't find package

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools

I'm currently facing a problem when trying to deploy the main to a console script using setuptools. I can only imagine, that there is something off with my application structure but I can't seem to find it.

The setup.py file looks like the following:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='automate',
    version='1.0',
    author='My name',
    author_email='test@mail.com',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'tornado',
        'rpi-rf',
        'RPi.GPIO',
        'SQLAlchemy'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'automate = project.main:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

The application structure is the following:

```
|-- venv
|-- setup.py
|-- project
    |-- database
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- api.py
    |   |-- base.py
    |   |-- config
    |   |   |-- dev.py
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- constants.py
    |   |-- models
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |-- tables
    |   |       |-- __init__.py
    |   |       |-- Signal.py
    |-- lib
    |   |-- handler.py
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |-- main.py
```

If I execute the main normally via command line, everything works fine. However, once I build the project (with no errors occurring) the script with gets installed in `venv/bin/automate' fails with this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'database'
```

in `main.py` at the database import statement

```
import database.base
```

Adding another __init__.py in the remote folder doesn't change anything

Maybe one of you knows what the problem is.

Comment: Try to change `import database.base` to `import project.database.base`.

Comment: If you want to retain the current imports, mark `project` dir as package root: add `package_dir={'': 'project'}` to `setup` arguments and change `find_packages()` to `find_packages('project')`.